# PHP DOM formatOutput work with XML file only one time

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm working with XML file. Data from form goes to this file.
First of all I create new XML file with root tag:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0')
$root = $doc->createElement('users');
$doc->appendChild($root);
$doc->save('path/filename.xml');
```

Then program open this file and add new data:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->load('path/filename.xml');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
...adding some data...
$doc->save('path/filename.xml');
```

When my program add data for the first time formatOutput looks well:

```
<users>
   <user>
      <name>Username1</name>
   </user>
</users>
```

But when program add data again formatOutput doesn't works:

```
<users>
   <user>
      <name>Username1</name>
   </user>
<user><name>Username2</name></user><user><name>Username3</name></user></users>
```

Comment: This may be a bug. Please can you check that:  http://kslt.tk/domdocument

Comment: What happens if you set `preserveWhiteSpace` to true? This is just a guess... sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the mistake. formatOutput and preserveWhiteSpace must be load:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');

$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$doc->load('path/filename.xml');
```

Thanks @kodmanyagha for the link.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense.